# URL Building Changes in Backend from 2.1.12 to 2.2.5

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.2.5

We are facing a regression during an Magento update from 2.1.12 to 2.2.5 which I want to understand better.

Our code looks like this and is in a block on a tab of the backend order sales

```
public function getPostUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('orderattachments/upload/index');
}
```

The result of this call includes the order_id key in the URL, for example is

https://example.com/admin/orderattachments/upload/index/order_id/123/key/ada29d4295d76eaabd08a9c8ec6842bf2891da81a3e3c3bd5d5b0f7b8af3c4b8/

Now in 2.2.5 we get only

https://example.com/admin/orderattachments/upload/index/key/ada29d4295d76eaabd08a9c8ec6842bf2891da81a3e3c3bd5d5b0f7b8af3c4b8/

After lots of debugging I tracked this down to

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.5/app/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Url.php#L231

vs

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.12/app/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Url.php#L231

In the recent version, _getRouteParams is not called anymore, which, during my debugging session, revealed that this adds they `order_id` parameter.

Is this intended (so essentially like https://xkcd.com/1172/) and I should now add the `order_id` manually or is this a regression in the core that should be patched?

Answer (score 0):

I have been told, that is makes more sense to supply that parameter manually and not to expect that request params are added automatically.

It was an easy fix:

```
public function getPostUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('orderattachments/upload/index',
         ['order_id' => $this->getOrder()->getId()]
    );
}
```

[image: Workflow]